# XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/apache­2/xdebug_remote.log'

Tags: php, apache, debugging, mamp

I am currently using MAMP as my localhost to work on some PHP. The first and last line in this error log are puzzling me.

The first line in the log states that it can not connect to the database with.

> $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'users');

[image]

I am entering the exact information that MAMP is telling me I need to input in order to connect to the database. As for the last line, it is telling me it can not open the remote debug file. This was not being displayed in my log files this morning and I have not changed anything since. Why would the log be displaying these errors?

```
[13-Nov-2016 05:12:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/functions/db.php on line 3
[13-Nov-2016 05:12:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Stack trace:
[13-Nov-2016 05:12:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/login.php:0
[13-Nov-2016 05:12:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP   2. include() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/login.php:1
[13-Nov-2016 05:12:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP   3. include() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/includes/header.php:1
[13-Nov-2016 05:12:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP   4. include() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/functions/init.php:7
[13-Nov-2016 05:12:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP   5. mysqli_connect() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/functions/db.php:3
[13-Nov-2016 05:13:27 Europe/Berlin] XDebug could not open the remote debug file '/var/log/apache­2/xdebug_remote.log'.
```